# VB.NET Textboxes come out fuzzy upon converting to a Bitmap image

Tags: vb.net, pdf, bitmap, pdfsharp

My application acts as a document template with textboxes for users to fill in. Once they've completed, they can "print" the document to a PDF using PDFsharp. This is done by converting the panel on which the textboxes are on to a bitmap image using the code below;

```
                ConditionReportConfig.PG1.Panel2.DrawToBitmap(Bitmap, New Rectangle(0, 0, Bitmap.Width, Bitmap.Height))
                frm_MsgPrint.lbl_Page.Text = "Page: 1" : frm_MsgPrint.lbl_Page.Refresh()
                frm_MsgPrint.PictureBox1.Image = Bitmap
                frm_MsgPrint.PictureBox1.Refresh()
                BXImage = Bitmap
                GFX.ScaleTransform(0.82)
                GFX.DrawImage(BXImage, 25, 0)
                GFX.Dispose()
                CDR1 = Nothing
```

Unfortunately, when the PDF pops up with the image the entire image, more so the text in the textboxes, are fuzzy. They aren't fuzzy to the point you can't read, but they do make reading the text incredibly stressful on your eyes.

I've tried adding various settings in such as;

```
                Dim Bitmap2 = New Bitmap(894, 1367)
                Using G As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(Bitmap2)
                    G.InterpolationMode = Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.Bicubic
                    G.DrawImage(Bitmap, 0, 0, 120, 150)
                End Using
```

I've even tried changing the font, size, even saving the bitmap as a TIFF, PNG and it still appears fuzzy. I would change printing methods, but the whole point of the panel is to be printed. Not only that but the panel contains images so I can't just print the text on the PDF.

Edit:
I've tried changing some of the interpolation settings, and it is slightly clearer but still a strain on your eyes.
Below is a snippet of the Bitmap image as a TIFF. Notice how the text in the textboxes is "Fuzzy" but the vertical text alongside is perfect. Is there really no way of getting textbox contents to be as sharp as the vertical text?

Blurry image with crystal clear vertical text:

[image: Blurry image with crystal clear vertical text]

Comment: Controls render their text in a way that is useful on an LCD monitor.  Typically using ClearType anti-aliasing, using red and blue fringes around the letter shape.  Works great on the monitor.  Does not work great on paper.  You have to stop using DrawToBitmap() to get ahead.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for alternatives to DrawToBitmap()? I can't seem to find anything which can turn a panel control into an image

Comment: As long as you keep the painting code for the panel in a separate method that takes a Graphics argument, so you can call it for printing as well, then you can get somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Create an `XImage` from your bitmap and set

```
image.Interpolate = false;
```

for that image. This is a hint for Adobe Reader not to smooth the image.

Also check that ClearType does not make your image blurry before adding it to the PDF.

Comment: Turns out the image itself is already blurry before adding it to the PDF itself, the Interpolate does help but the image still causes significant eyestrain. I added a screenshot to show what I mean

Comment: The rainbow-coloured blurriness of the horizontal text is the result of ClearType. ClearType is not used for vertical text.